# Docker-compose volumes with DigitalOcean

Tags: docker-compose, digital-ocean, volumes

My docker build works on my devices. When I upload to digital-ocean server and execute the "docker-compose up -d" command, all containers are launched except for "frontend". The problem is with "volumes", when I remove it it all works.
How to solve this problem? I need this property to remain.

```
frontend_1 | > test-docker@0.1.0 dev /app/client
frontend_1 | > next dev
frontend_1 |
frontend_1 | sh: 1: next: not found
frontend_1 | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
frontend_1 | npm ERR! syscall spawn
frontend_1 | npm ERR! file sh
frontend_1 | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
frontend_1 | npm ERR! test-docker@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
frontend_1 | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
frontend_1 | npm ERR!
frontend_1 | npm ERR! Failed at the test-docker@0.1.0 dev script.
frontend_1 | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
frontend_1 | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
frontend_1 |
frontend_1 | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
frontend_1 | npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-31T01_14_30_246Z-debug.log
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app/server
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  frontend:
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app/client
    depends_on:
      - api
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - apiDB:/data/db

volumes:
  apiDB:

version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app/server
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  frontend:
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app/client
    depends_on:
      - api
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - apiDB:/data/db

volumes:
  apiDB:
```

./client/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

RUN mkdir -p /app/client
WORKDIR /app/client

COPY . /app/client
RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Comment: Does `./client` directory exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists. Everything works fine on my computers, but it doesn't work on digitalocean



`user@user-H81M-S2V:~/Документы/m-climate$ ls`
`client              next-env.d.ts  README.md  _static`
`docker-compose.yml  node_modules   server     static`

Answer (score 0):

I discourage your use of the image's build context (e.g. `build: context: ./client`) to be the same as the container's volume mount (e.g. `volumes: ./client:${SOMETHING}`) and this is possibly the issue.

The build context on your localhost is used to build the image and you `COPY` this to the image's `/app/client` directory.

When you run the image, you attempt to replace the (previously copied to the image) directory (`/app/client`) with the now empty directory on the Droplet.

If your `Dockerfile` is correct (and your local host's `./client` is copied), you may discard the `volume` mount for `frontend` (because it's already under `/app/client`).